# How do I recursively mirror a directory and its contents with puppet?

Tags: puppet

Let's say I have a module with `files/etc/foo/{conf0, conf1, conf2, conf3, etc}`. It's simple enough to place each of these files when the number of them is small:

```
file { 'conf0':
    path => '/etc/foo/conf0',
    ensure => true,
    source => 'puppet:///.../etc/foo/conf0',
}
```

and repeat. But there's a fair bit of duplication involved, and it's tedious to maintain if there are several configuration files. I would like to ensure that `files/etc/foo/` is mirrored onto a given path. That is to say,

```
file { 'etc foo confs':
   path => '/etc/foo',
   ensure => recursive,
   source => 'puppet:///.../etc/foo',
}
```

would create `/etc/foo/conf0`, `/etc/foo/conf1` and so on. Is this possible?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Sure - the `files` type has a `recurse` option (and `recurselimit` if you want to limit how deep into the directory it goes).

```
file { 'etc foo confs':
   path => '/etc/foo',
   source => 'puppet:///.../etc/foo',
   recurse => true,
}
```

Comment: The other thing to keep in mind if doing this is the number of files that Puppet is going to have to maintain connections for. It would not take long to run out of file descriptors and puppet start running into trouble. I've ran into this problem before trying to do this very task.

Comment: @JeremyBouse Thank you; that's very useful information.